# Is it possible create a copy of Entity Framework context's Instance to make parallel queries

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

Stack: AngularJs, Web API, Entity Framework, SQL Server.

I need to query SQL Server with parallel queries to get the result faster.

I am using Web API and can split the query into separate Web API calls, as it creates a new copy of database context for every Web API call, ***but I am wondering if it's possible to do it inside one Web API call***. ( I assume I need to create a separate copy of context for every parallel query, as Entity Framework does not allow to call multiple queries in parallel for the same instance of context).

I am using Unity DI container for creating context's instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can set-up your container to create a new instance per call... On Unity, I would suggest you to create a named entry (using `PerResolveLifetimeManager`) and leave the existing one for the rest of the application (just to segregate approaches)...

oh and remember to dispose of these new contexts manually!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about querying your database on multiple threads then yes, you have to spin up a new context instance per thread. But be careful if you are modifying the database/data in any way that you validate your query results in each thread or you could end up with results you don't necessarily want.

I've multi-threaded inserts into a database before (not really the recommended path but I was doing it more as a test to see if I could) and you just have to remember to keep all connections and entities separated per thread or EF will yell at you.